# Ponyorm with psycopg2: server closed the connection unexpectedly (session timeout?)

Tags: python, python-3.6, psycopg2, ponyorm

I'm using the standard pony 'architecture' as in the examples. If I do the following steps, the problem occurs:

1. Start application. I can work with the database properly
2. I can do stress tests all night, everything goes well
3. If I don't do anything for like 10-15 minutes and then I try to execute something, I get the following exception message:

> ```
> server closed the connection unexpectedly
> This probably means the server terminated abnormally
> before or while processing the request.
> ```

Versions:

- pony.**version**
  '0.7.3'
- psycopg2.**version**
  '2.7.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'
- python 3.6

After a while, the cursor get's disconnected, `psycopg2` throws an `Operational Error`, which is re-raised by pony.

*Note:* I have already created an issue for **ponyorm**, however I'm not 100% sure, that it's pony's bug. The issue with some investigation is here: https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/357

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this is a bug in PonyORM which we just fixed:
https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/commit/f763694212c07ccaf73eafd64c8f6aa901f7ac81